# R - Shiny - How to align buttons/icons in a single row in wellpanel?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have placed 3 button icons in wellpanel.

The problem is all the 3 icons do not appear in one single row (*"screenshot" icon appears in the first line where the next 2 icons appear in the second row*).

I tried aligning with "fixedRow" and "style" but could not achieve.

Can anyone please help me to do this?

Thanks...

Script:

```
TableA = data.frame(Product = c('iPhone', 'Macbook', 'Airpod', 'Macbook', 'Airpod', 'Macbook', 'iPhone'), East = c(1:7), West = c(5:11), North = c(15:21), South = c(24:30))

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(knitr)
library(gt)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

header = dashboardHeader(title = 'Shiny Dashboard', titleWidth = 400)

sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  
  wellPanel(
    
    "Export Options", id = "DownloadPanel", style = "background: #222d32; max-height: 145px; max-width: 220px; align-items: center",
    
    
    fixedRow(tags$div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:center; horizontal-align:center", class = "row-fluid",
                      
                      screenshotButton(selector="#TableC", label = NULL, filename = paste("Summary")),
                      
                      downloadButton(outputId = "SummaryExcelDownload", label = NULL, icon = icon("file-excel"), class = "butt1",
                                     tags$head(tags$style(".butt{background-color:white;} .butt1{color: #217346 !important;}"))),
                      
                      downloadButton(outputId = "SummaryPdfDownload", label = NULL, icon = icon("file-pdf"), class = "butt2",
                                     tags$head(tags$style(".butt{background-color:white;} .butt2{color: #b30c00 !important;}")))
                      
                      
    ))
  )
)


body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("mainpanel"))

ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

############

server = function(input, output, session)
  
{
  
  output$mainpanel = renderUI({
    
    fluidRow(tabBox(width = 250, height = 100,
                    tabPanel("Apple Sales", value = 'tab1', gt_output(outputId = "TableC")%>% withSpinner(color="#3483CA", type = 1, size = 2))
    ))
  })
  
  
  TableB = as.data.frame(TableA) %>%
    
    gt() %>%
    
    grand_summary_rows(columns = 2:5, fns = list(TotalSales = "sum")) %>%
    
    tab_options(grand_summary_row.background.color = "#DDEBF7") %>%
    
    cols_width(columns = 1 ~ px(1), columns = 2 ~ px(300), everything() ~ px(100)) %>%
    
    tab_spanner(label = "Sales", columns = 3:6)
  
  output$TableC = render_gt(expr = TableB)
  

  output$SummaryExcelDownload = downloadHandler(
    filename = "Summary.pdf",
    content = function(file) {write.xlsx(TableC, file)})
  
  
  output$SummaryPdfDownload = downloadHandler(
    filename = "Summary.pdf",
    content = function(file) {write.xlsx(TableC, file)})

  }


############

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Output:

[image]

*Note:
Please ignore the "server" arguments for excel and pdf downloads (output$SummaryExcelDownload and output$SummaryPdfDownload) as I'm still exploring to correct the same.*

Comment: Wrapping in a `div()` should display in a row, as long as the width is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shinyscreenshot)

header = dashboardHeader(title = 'Shiny Dashboard', titleWidth = 400)

sidebar = dashboardSidebar( width=300,
      h5(strong("If you want to see buttons in a row, just use div()")),
      fluidRow(div(
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 135px ;", screenshotButton("btn21", "Buttons")),
      
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px ;", downloadButton("btn22", "in a")),
      
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px ;", downloadButton("btn23", "row"))
      
      )),
      div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:center; horizontal-align:center", class = "row-fluid",
          actionButton("btn11", "Buttons"),
          actionButton("btn12", "in a"),
          actionButton("btn13", "col")
          ),
      div(
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 95px ;", actionButton("btn31", "Buttons")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px ;", actionButton("btn32", "in a")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 65px ;", actionButton("btn33", "row"))
      )
      
)

body <- dashboardBody()

ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]