# The selectinput function doesn't display the whole list at once in the UI

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

The pickerInput function from the shinyWidgets package doesn't display the whole complete list of choices, the same thing happens with the original selectInput  function from the shiny package. The image of what is happening is below.

Changed browsers from safari to chrome but still the same issue.
safari version 14.1 and chrome version Version 90.0.4430.212.
I also uninstalled and reinstalled shiny but same result. any suggestions please

[image]

code  used is below

```
fluidRow(column(width = 3, id ="column_selector1"),
                         column(width = 9, id ="column_selector2",
                    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%", "25%", "35%","15%"),
                                #cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 5px"),
                                pickerInput("months",label = NULL, choices = months_list, multiple = T, selected = NULL,options = list(title = "Months",`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 2")),
                                pickerInput("years",label = NULL,choices = years_list, multiple = T,selected = "2021", options = list(title = "Years",`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 2")),
                                pickerInput("state",label = NULL, choices = states$state_name, multiple = T,selected = states$state_name, options = list(title = "State",`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 2")),
                                                                                                           
                                actionButton("update",label = "Update",style = "bordered", color = "success")
                    )
                    ))
```

There CSS code I used (I am a newbie to css)

```
}
#column_about_us,#column_selector1,#column_selector2 {
  background-color: #d5ebf2;
  border-radius: none;
  margin: none;
  height: none; width: none;
 /* box-shadow: none;*/
}
.col-sm-5{background-color: #ebf5f5;
                   /* border:2px solid #16c0f2;
                    border-style: outset;*/
                    border-radius: 5px;
                     margin: 5px 3px;
                      height: 200px;width: 24%;
                      box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            }
```

**Below is what I want to achieve.**

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408532/selectinput-choices-are-hidden-behind-downloadbutton-in-shiny-app) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it (to keep splitLayout) is given below.

```
fluidRow(column(width = 3, id ="column_selector1"),
         column(width = 9, id ="column_selector2",
                splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%", "25%", "35%","15%"),
                            #cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 5px"),
                            pickerInput("months",label = NULL, choices = months_list, multiple = T, selected = NULL,options = list(title = "Months",`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 2")),
                            pickerInput("years",label = NULL,choices = years_list, multiple = T,selected = "2021", options = list(title = "Years",`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 2")),
                            pickerInput("state",label = NULL, choices = states$state_name, multiple = T,selected = states$state_name, options = list(title = "State",`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 2")),
                            
                            actionButton("update",label = "Update",style = "bordered", color = "success"),
                            tags$head(tags$style(HTML(" .shiny-split-layout > div {
                                 overflow: visible;
                              }
                              ")))
                )
         ))
```

Credit goes to Xiongbing Jin, and see his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077388/shiny-splitlayout-and-selectinput-issue)